# How to create a function in the first-order language?

Tags: first-order-logic

In mathematical proof,we usually create a function based on the formula like "∀x∃!yR(x,y)" just in the natural language.
However, how could we express this process in the first-order language?
And,haven't the function already been specified in symbol library?If so,how can we create a new function?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_by_definitions

Comment: Thanks a lot.It does help.

Comment: See also [Understanding Extension by definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4363153/understanding-extension-by-definition)

Comment: another way to give new names is the $\iota$-operator of definite descriptions which you may add conservatively to first order logic