# Please simply explain “extension by definitions” in logic

Tags: logic

I am self learning logic and have come across the concept of “extension by definitions”. Unfortunately, Wikipedia has proved to be a bit unfriendly to my dysfunctional brain.

I understand the concept and idea behind it, just not the notational aspect. If anyone could walk me through the notation it would be a massive blessing. A specific example I am stuck on is the successor function and introducing constants other than 0 into the language of natural numbers. Thank you

Comment: Which course, textbook, or set of lecture notes are you following? Wikipedia should mostly serve as a reference but not as a didactic introduction to a beginner.

Comment: I was using “a friendly i introduction to mathematical logic” by Leary, but they leave alot out and unexplained

Comment: Search on this site... in a nutshell, add a new predicate, relation, constant to the language through a def (a dedicated axiom) and prove that the "extended" theory does NOT prove new theorem not involving the newly defined terms wrt the original theory.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4363153/understanding-extension-by-definition) as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820673/semantics-and-logical-structure-in-definitions)